# Webpage looks fine at 1080, but higher resolutions seem to "zoom in" on the elements so there is no padding on the sides

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/porsche1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

body{
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

html,body{
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

header{
    width: 1650px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 10;
}

nav{
    left: inherit;
    right: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

When viewed on a 1920x1080 screen or lower, it looks fine.  The spacing on the sides is apparent.  However on higher resolution screens (laptop has a 4k display), the elements inside the nav are touching the edge of the screen.

How can I make the page consistent across desktop resolutions?

Comment: some html would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you're using a JPEG file as your background, at a variable resolution. `porche.jpg` might not look bad at 1080p, but, at 4K, your browser might scale `porche.jpg` to fit that 4K space. Upscaled JPEG images are never a good thing.

Not only that, but you have 25 pixels of padding at both 1080p and 4K. I have no idea how big your monitors are, but, if I'm correct, the 4K one has a higher DPI than the 1080p monitor. In this case, I'd change this bit...

```
padding-top: 25px;
```

into this (hoping CSS takes floating percentages, if it doesn't, use `2%`)...

```
padding-top: 2.314815%
```

In addition, you have your header's width explicitly at `1650px`. This may be fine at 1080p, but at lower resolutions, this may clip, and at higher resolutions, it won't be the desired width.

I would change this...

```
width: 1650px;
```

to this:

```
width: 85.9375%;
```

I'm no graphics designer, but, if you can avoid using fixed pixel sizes, do so. That way, you can accommodate for all sorts of different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the input!  I will try this tonight when I get home, and will update you on the results.